# Changing domain or label from signal more than once

Tags: vega

I'm trying to use signals to change the scale domain or axis labels on a Vega chart on a webpage. I put debug expressions in the signals and also in the scales and axes to verify that the signal is receiving the values sent from javascript (e.g. `view.signal("xdomainMin",0);`) and see the messages in the console.

When vegaEmbed first initializes from the spec, everything comes up fine. In the javascript console, the signal update expression prints out the initial value, and then the scale domain and axes title expressions print out the same initial values from the signal.

However, when I send signals from javascript to change the domain or label after that, then the signals are received and print to the console, but the domain and title signal expressions do not print out anything after the first time. It's like they can only be set once, permanently.

If I remove the `value:` initializer from the signal, then the console shows that the value is undefined, and subsequently when sending a signal value, then the signal does takes the value but it does not get propagated to the domain or label.

If `view.getState()` is logged to console, it shows that the signals were updated with new values. However, the chart on the page still has the old axis labels and old domain scale.

It's strange, because I've seen other example code where people are saying that they were able to modify the domain dynamically from javascript. For example: [this SO question about changing the domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44421951/changing-the-domain-of-a-scale-without-shifting-the-entire-plot)

Here's a simplified spec:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
    "autosize": { "type": "fit", "contains": "padding" },
    "padding": 5,
    "width": 300,
    "height": 300,
    "data": [{
        "name": "xy",
        "values": [
            {"1": 1.0, "2": 12.0},
            {"1": 10.4, "2": 22.2},
            {"1": 20.8, "2": 42.5}
        ]
    }],
    "signals": [
        { "name": "xkey", "value": "1", "update": "debug('inside signal, xkey is ', xkey)" },
        { "name": "ykey", "value": "2", "update": "debug('inside signal, ykey is ', ykey)" },
        { "name": "xlabel", "value": "XXX", "update": "debug('inside signal, xlabel is ', xlabel)" },
        { "name": "ylabel", "value": "YYY", "update": "debug('inside signal, ylabel is ', ylabel)" },
        { "name": "xdomainMin", "value": -100, "update": "debug('inside signal, xdomainMin is ', xdomainMin)" },
        { "name": "xdomainMax", "value":  100, "update": "debug('inside signal, xdomainMax is ', xdomainMax)" }
    ],
    "scales": [{
        "name": "xscale",
        "domain": [0, 100],
        "domainMin": { "signal": "debug('DOMAIN CHANGE xdomainMin =', xdomainMin)" },
        "domainMax": { "signal": "debug('DOMAIN CHANGE xdomainMax =', xdomainMax)" },
        "range": "width"
    }, {
        "name": "yscale",
        "domain": [0, 100],
        "range": "height"
    }],
    "axes": [
        { "orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale", "title": { "signal": "debug('CHANGE X LABEL =', xlabel)" } },
        { "orient": "left", "scale": "yscale", "title": { "signal": "debug('CHANGE Y LABEL =', ylabel)"} }
    ],
    "marks": [
        {
            "type": "symbol",
            "from": { "data": "xy" },
            "encode": {
                "enter": {
                    "x": { "scale": "xscale", "field": "1"},
                    "y": { "scale": "yscale", "field": "2"}
                },
                "update": {
                    "x": { "scale": "xscale", "field": {"signal": "debug('x ', datum[xkey], xkey)"} },
                    "y": { "scale": "yscale", "field": {"signal": "debug('y ', datum[ykey], ykey)"} },
                    "fill": { "value": "steelblue" }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and the javascript signal calls are simply like this:

```js
    vega_view.signal("xlabel", "test");
    vega_view.signal("xdomainMin", 0);
    vega_view.signal("xdomainMax", 42);
    vega_view.runAsync()
        .then( ()=>{
            console.log("\nSTATE:")
            console.log(vega_view.getState());
            console.log("\n");
        });
```

I can't even imagine that it's not possible to change an axis label via a signal. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example where the title and domain can be updated.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A basic bar chart example, with value labels shown upon mouse hover.",
  "width": 400,
  "padding": 5,

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"category": "A", "amount": 28},
        {"category": "B", "amount": 55},
        {"category": "C", "amount": 43},
        {"category": "D", "amount": 91},
        {"category": "E", "amount": 81},
        {"category": "F", "amount": 53},
        {"category": "G", "amount": 19},
        {"category": "H", "amount": 87}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "domain",
      "value": ["A", "B", "C"]
    },
    {
      "name": "title",
      "value": "Title"
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "point",
      "domain": {"signal": "domain"},
      "range": "width"
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    { "orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale", "title": {"signal": "title"} }
  ]
}
```

There are a few problems in your spec. First, the update expressions debug expressions are incorrect. The `debug` function is a noop with a side effect and should only take a value. Second, the `field` should be the name of the field, not a value. Here is the fixed example that works.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
    "autosize": { "type": "fit", "contains": "padding" },
    "padding": 5,
    "width": 300,
    "height": 300,
    "data": [{
        "name": "xy",
        "values": [
            {"1": 1.0, "2": 12.0},
            {"1": 10.4, "2": 22.2},
            {"1": 20.8, "2": 42.5}
        ]
    }],
    "signals": [
        { "name": "xkey", "value": "1" },
        { "name": "ykey", "value": "2" },
        { "name": "xlabel", "value": "XXX" },
        { "name": "ylabel", "value": "YYY"},
        { "name": "xdomainMin", "value": -100 },
        { "name": "xdomainMax", "value":  100 }
    ],
    "scales": [{
        "name": "xscale",
        "domain": [0, 1],
        "domainMin": { "signal": "xdomainMin" },
        "domainMax": { "signal": "xdomainMax" },
        "range": "width"
    }, {
        "name": "yscale",
        "domain": [0, 100],
        "range": "height"
    }],
    "axes": [
        { "orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale", "title": { "signal": "xlabel" } },
        { "orient": "left", "scale": "yscale", "title": { "signal": "ylabel"} }
    ],
    "marks": [
        {
            "type": "symbol",
            "from": { "data": "xy" },
            "encode": {
                "enter": {
                    "x": { "scale": "xscale", "field": "1"},
                    "y": { "scale": "yscale", "field": "2"}
                },
                "update": {
                    "x": { "scale": "xscale", "field": {"signal": "xkey"} },
                    "y": { "scale": "yscale", "field": {"signal": "ykey"} },
                    "fill": { "value": "steelblue" }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Removing the update expression containing the debug function from the signals fixed it. Thanks so much! If I leave the debug function in the signal expressions for scales/domain and axes/title, then it still works and is helpful for debugging. Oh also, I wasn't trying to give values in the marks fields, it just looks that way because the keys on the data are "1" and "2". I actually had several keys and was trying to select between them using a signal, but gave up trying to do that, and just munge the data in typescript instead.